# Prevent Parallel operation executing in sequential batches

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.for

I have 8 logical processors. When executing the following code

```
public void test()
{
    Parallel.For(1, 1001, i => { IntensiveWork(i); });
}

private static void IntensiveWork(int i)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    Thread.Sleep(r.Next(i * 1));
}
```

I notice that the `Parallel.For` makes multiple batches of 8 jobs. Each batch will be executed sequentially. The issue in this is that if 7/8 jobs in the batch finished, then the next batch will keep waiting for the last job to finish. This means that 7 cores will not be busy. Is there a better way to implement parallelism is C#, in which once a job in the batch finishes it will assign that core another job.

Comment: What happens if you use `Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(1, 1000), i => { IntensiveWork(i); });`?

Comment: The Microsoft documentation on [Parallel Programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/) is quite extensive. Especially the linked ebook [PATTERNS OF PARALLEL PROGRAMMING](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=86b3d32b-ad26-4bb8-a3ae-c1637026c3ee&displaylang=en) is an interesting read and also explains how partitioning works. See also [Custom Parallel Partitioning](http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/custom-parallel-partitioning-with-net-4/224600406).

Answer (score 1):

You can make single queue that multiple tasks will read from.

```
static void test()
{
    ConcurrentQueue<int> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 1000));
    int taskCount = Environment.ProcessorCount;
    Task[] tasks = new Task[taskCount];
    for (int taskIndex = 0; taskIndex < taskCount; taskIndex++)
    {
        Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => IntensiveWorkTask(queue));
        tasks[taskIndex] = task;
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
}

private static void IntensiveWorkTask(ConcurrentQueue<int> queue)
{
    while (queue.TryDequeue(out int value))
        IntensiveWork(value);
}

private static void IntensiveWork(int i)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    Thread.Sleep(r.Next(i * 1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - just NuGet `System.Reactive` and then add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
public void test()
{
    IObservable<Unit> query =
        Observable
            .Range(1, 1000)
            .SelectMany(i =>
                Observable
                    .Start(() => IntensiveWork(i)));

    IDisposable subscription = query.Subscribe();
}

private static Random r = new Random();

private static void IntensiveWork(int i)
{
    Thread.Sleep(r.Next(i * 1));
}
```

Play with the `.Subscribe(...` to be able to respond to each work item when it is completed.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
Parallel.For(1, 1001, parallelOptions, i => IntensiveWork(i));
```

You should do:

```
IEnumerable<int> source = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000);

Partitioner<int> partitioner = Partitioner
    .Create(source, EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering);
    
Parallel.ForEach(partitioner, parallelOptions, i => IntensiveWork(i));
```

The [partitioning strategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/custom-partitioners-for-plinq-and-tpl) of the [`Parallel.For`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for) is a combination of range partitioning and chunk partitioning, which is not appropriate for your case, and cannot be configured. What you want is a partitioner with load balancing behavior, with chunk partitioning disabled. That's why you have to switch to [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach), and configure the partitioner with the [`EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.enumerablepartitioneroptions) option.

The `parallelOptions` is shown below. It's always a good idea to specify explicitly the [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism), for example to [`Environment.ProcessorCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.processorcount), instead of relying on the default `-1` (unlimited) configuration that saturates the `ThreadPool`.

```
ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount
};
```