# Parallel.ForEach blocked on long iteration

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, blocking, parallel.foreach

I've been using `Parallel.ForEach` to do some time-consuming processing on collections of items.  The processing is actually handled by an external command line tool and I cannot change that.  However, it seems that the `Parallel.ForEach` will get "stuck" on a long running item from the collection.  I've distilled the problem down and can show that `Parallel.ForEach` is, in fact, waiting for this long one to finish and not allowing any others through.  I've written a console app to demonstrate the problem:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace testParallel
{
    class Program
    {
        static int inloop = 0;
        static int completed = 0;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // initialize an array integers to hold the wait duration (in milliseconds)
            var items = Enumerable.Repeat(10, 1000).ToArray();
            
            // set one of the items to 10 seconds
            items[50] = 10000;


            // Initialize our line for reporting status
            Console.Write(0.ToString("000") + " Threads, " + 0.ToString("000") + " completed");

            // Start the loop in a task (to avoid SO answers having to do with the Parallel.ForEach call, itself, not being parallel)
            var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Process(items));

            // Wait for the operations to compelte
            t.Wait();

            // Report finished
            Console.WriteLine("\nDone!");
        }

        static void Process(int[] items)
        {
            // SpinWait (not sleep or yield or anything) for the specified duration
            Parallel.ForEach(items, (msToWait) =>
            {
                // increment the counter for how many threads are in the loop right now
                System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref inloop);

                // determine at what time we shoule stop spinning
                var e = DateTime.Now + new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, msToWait);
                
                // spin until the target time
                while (DateTime.Now < e) /* no body -- just a hard loop */;
                
                // count another completed
                System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref completed);

                // we're done with this iteration
                System.Threading.Interlocked.Decrement(ref inloop);

                // report status
                Console.Write("\r" + inloop.ToString("000") + " Threads, " + completed.ToString("000") + " completed");

            });
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I make an array of int to store the number of milliseconds a given operation takes.  I set them all to 10 except for one, which I set to 10000 (so, 10 seconds).  I kick off the `Parallel.ForEach` in a task and process each integer in a hard spin wait (so it shouldn't be yielding or sleeping or anything).
On each iteration, I report how many iterations are *in* the body of the loop right now, and how many iterations we have completed.  Mostly, it goes along fine.  However, toward the end (time-wise), it reports "001 Threads, 987 Completed".

My question is why doesn't it use 7 of the other cores to work on the remaining 13 "jobs"?  This one long-running iteration should not keep it from processing other elements in the collection, right?

This example happens to be a fixed collection, but it could easily be set to be an enumerable.  We wouldn't want to stop fetching the next item in the enumerable just because one was taking a long time.

Comment: Related: [Prevent Parallel operation executing in sequential batches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54846678/prevent-parallel-operation-executing-in-sequential-batches).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer (or at least, *an* answer).  It has to do with the chunk partitioning.  The SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427214/chunk-partitioning-ienumerable-in-parallel-foreach) got it for me.  So basically, at the top of my "Process" function, if I change from this:

```
        static void Process(int[] items)
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(items, (msToWait) => { ... });
        }
```

to  this

```
        static void Process(int[] items)
        {
            var partitioner = Partitioner.Create(items, EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering);
            Parallel.ForEach(partitioner, (msToWait) => { ... });
        }
```

it grabs the work one at a time.  For the more typical case of a parallel for each, where the body doesn't take more than a second, I can certainly see chunking the sets of work.  In my use case, however, each body part can take anywhere from half a second to 5 hours.  I certainly would not want a bunch of the 10-second variety elements to be blocked by one 5 hour element.  So, in this case, the overhead of "one-at-a-time" is well worth it.

Comment: In case anyone is interested in digging in more, check out https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Parallel.cs
I was interested because I could reproduce the exact result you posted in the question. When I modified the code to use a `Dictionary<int, int>` for `items`, I saw a different and improved result with only one additional task held up by the long running task. The following indicates why: https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/60a4f8b853f60a424e36c7bf60f9b5b5f1973ed1/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Parallel.cs#L2237